# Bmw 318i msport 2007

Tags: transmission, clutch, bmw

I have a 3 series 318i 2ltr 2007 m sport and I can not get my clutch to release. 
The cdv was leaking.  We changed the clutch master cylinder and slave cylinder and bled the system for air.  I can not get into gear while the car is running.  the petal feels like it has pressure but it's like the pressure plate is not releasing.  I have a hard time when it's running getting in to 3rd or 1st.

Comment: assuming it's approved, i edited this for clarity.  You'll get much better results with proper sentences since it was hard to understand even the details of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't select any gears with the engine running then the problem is likely hydraulic.  Try pressure bleeding or even reverse pressure bleeding the hydraulic system as it does sound like you still have air trapped somewhere.